# What's wrong in this function?(the intention is to delete docs)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**delete account**

```
  const handleDelete = async function () {
    const userData = [
      `${user.email}_data/bookmarked_movies/bookmarks`,
      `${user.email}_data/bookmarked_movies/bookmarks_trace`,
    ];

    await Promise.all(
      userData.map((colRef) => {
        const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(db, colRef));
        querySnapshot.map((document) => {
          deleteDoc(doc(db, colRef, document.id));
        });
      })
    );
  };
```

The intention is to delete all docs from the collection by iterating through it, but I catch a lot of errors. What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `querySnapshot` result does not contain a `.map` method and `getDocs` must be `await`ed. You'll need to use `.forEach` to process the results then build a map of `deleteDoc` promises manually.

```
const promises = [];
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, colRef));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  promises.push(deleteDoc(doc.ref));
});
await Promise.all(promises);
```